# Face contours getting detected as 2 contours with the same drawing

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing a Project about Face Detection, thus far I want to detect the face as one whole contour, but here it's not the case.

I have the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> biggestcontours;
Mat canny_output;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        Rect bounding_rect;

        /// Detect edges using canny
        Canny(src, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);
        /// Find contours
        findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true);
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contours_poly[i]);
            contour_sizes.push_back(contours[i].size());
            drawContours(drawing_all, contours, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        }
std::sort(contour_sizes.begin(), contour_sizes.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            if (contours[i].size() == contour_sizes[contour_sizes.size() - 1] || contours[i].size() == contour_sizes[contour_sizes.size() - 2]
                || contours[i].size() == contour_sizes[contour_sizes.size() - 3])
            {
                if (contours[i].size() < 300) continue;
                biggestcontours.push_back(contours[i]);
                rectangles.push_back(boundRect[i]);
                drawContours(drawing_biggest_3, contours, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
                rectangle(drawing_biggest_3, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), Scalar(150, 100, 255), 2);
            }
        }
nbcontours = biggestcontours.size();
        stringstream ss;
        ss << nbcontours;
        string str = ss.str();
        putText(drawing_biggest_3, str, cv::Point(30, 30),
            FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, Scalar(200, 200, 250), 1, cv::LINE_AA);
```

The biggestcontours vector is cleared (biggestcontours.clear()) at every frame.
When I show my face, the number of contours is detected as 2 but my face is showing a clear contour with no separation. I tried drawing the two contours each on an individual Mat image, they showed the same contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the retrieval mode you are using. You chose `RETR_TREE` mode to find contours. As the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) says:

> CV_RETR_TREE retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full
> hierarchy of nested contours

Its finding inner and outer contours at the same time thats why it detects 2 contour. It can be better to use `RETR_EXTERNAL` mode in your case:

> CV_RETR_EXTERNAL retrieves only the extreme outer contours.